# Android Studio Error: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am completely new to Android Studio so it may sound a silly thing to an experienced person.

I am getting an error in Android Studio which states:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value 
value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] 
AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] 
AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at 
AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.
```

I have Googled this and tried looking into it to solve it on my own, however, similar issues that I have found aren't quite the same errors.

I'm not experienced enough to understand and generate a fix for it although I understand some of it.

It may be the case that I need to provide more information for this so please let me know if so.

*EDIT*:

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.g732d.appname"
    >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Patients" />

        <activity android:name=".NewPatient" />

        <activity android:name=".StartActivity"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle (Project: appname)**:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (Module: App)**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.g732d.appname"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
}
```

*SECOND EDIT:*

Following the answer by Arefeh and the comment by Kunal, I changed the version mismatch by replacing `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'` with `compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2'`.

For this to work, I had to add `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` in the `build.gradle (Project: appname)` file within `allprojects{}` (have updated above to illustrate this).

Now I keep getting a render error which says `failed to instantiate one or more classes`. The classes are different for each activity depending on what I've used in the activity e.g.

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
    - android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Post your `manifest` and `build.gradle`

Comment: Thanks dustblue, I've just added them by means of an edit.

Comment: Please add the other gradle file as well.
`build.gradle (Module : app)`

Comment: Thanks Kunal, didn't realize. All done.

Comment: Most probably its a mismatch between the appcompat (v26) and design library (v25).  Try replacing `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'` with `compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2'`.

Comment: I've done as you suggested although I'm getting new errors which I've added to the question in an update. Do you know how to fix it sorry?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is for difference between versions of support libraries. Change your version of design library to 26 or higher. 
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I go about changing that sorry? It says 26 in the code I've attached so I'm assuming it is a setting although I may be wrong?

Comment: In your build.gradle file, in dependencies part, replace compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+' with compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'. 
You should use same version of support library in all of you dependencies and versions :)

Answer (score 0):

What seems to have worked in this instance, is going to `File > Project Structure` then in `app > Properties` where it says `Compile Sdk Version` and `Build Tools Version`, I changed them to `API 25: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat)` and `25.0.3` respectively. After which I synced the project and gradle and then rebuilt.
I then repeated the process and changed back again to `API 26: Android 8.0 (O)` and `26.0.0`. So far it is working again although I will update if this changes.